# Google Maps JS iFrame Title?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Is it possible to add a title attribute to the google maps iframe if it is being rendered by javascript?

Here is an example of how this is being rendered in the html page.

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;" title="test"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>
```

I understand you can add a title if referencing an iframe directly e.g.

```
<iframe title="test"/>
```

but wasn't sure if it can be altered when producing the map this way.

Comment: is this [the API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=fr#MapOptions) you are using? If so, the doc tells nothing about adding a title. But that should be easy to add your own title, like a `div`, positioned either outside the frame, or in position absolute on top of it.

Comment: This is more for accessibility and validator issues rather than for visual purposes.

Comment: what do you mean by accessibility and validator issues? for the first, your div already has an `id` to access it, and for the second, `title` is a universal attribute that is not mandatory for a div or iframe. By the way, you are talking about iframes, but the map is actually not rendered in an iframe, [see fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mgeoaL4z/4/): inside the fiddle iframe, the map is rendered in divs, there is an empty iframe inside, but it's probably here for communication purposes with google, it has nothing in it.

Comment: I see, the information I was provided for the issue was 'Google Maps iframe requires title attribute (title = "")' so I believe this was picked up in w3c validator or sitemorse

Comment: While the Google Maps doesn't load up as in iframe in modern browsers, it does load as in iframe as a fallback for some older browsers, including some of the ones used to test accessibility.  I would like to know if someone finds out how to do this - unfortunately we've had cases where the government (enforcing the law) does not care about "false positives" but only see the tool which shows that error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Maps API has a way of adding event listeners to it's maps.  Since you will only need to use it once:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/event#event.addListenerOnce

I was able to pass the Lighthouse A11y audit after adding the following:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', () => {
  document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].title = "Google Maps";
})
```

(Add the snippet below the map variable.)